# Why is my WiFi name registering differently on my laptop but correctly via ethernet?

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm unable to connect to the Internet via WiFi as the name is registering differently.

My WiFi name is MyWifi but it's registering #yW2fi and am unable to connect.

But it works fine with correct name via ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because thats not your wifi network (#yW2fi) and your wifi settings are hiding your own network SID.
you can unhide/hide your SID in the settings of your router. Normally you can login to your router by using it's IP address in a webbrowser. What router do you use?

Comment: How would I unhide my network SID?

Comment: yes I know I must have 50 points to comment. However I can comment your post? And It will be the answer soon.now.